# Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I'm trying to create a pdf from a spreadsheet in a shared google disk, but i'm trying to figure out what is blocking to generate the pdf.
The problem is situated in this line:

```
var driveFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
```

Here is the whole code:

```
function createPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Article 19");
  var folderName=ss.getRangeByName("NumAff").getValue();
  var fileName='Tableau 19.09_' + ss.getRangeByName("NumAff").getValue();

  sheet.showSheet();
  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
  const pdfOpts = '&top_margin=0.30&bottom_margin=0.30&left_margin=0.25&right_margin=0.25'
    +'&size=LETTER' // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    +'&portrait=true' // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    +'&fitw=true' // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    +'&sheetnames=false' // hide optional headers
    +'&printtitle=false' //and footers
    +'&pagenumbers=false' // hide page numbers 
    +'&gridlines=false' //and gridlines
    +'&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'
    +'&vertical_alignment=CENTER'
    +'&fzr=true' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +'&attachment=false'
    +'&gid='+gid;

  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  var options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}
  var blobresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var blob=blobresponse.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() +".pdf" );
  var driveFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next(); 
  var file = driveFolder.createFile(blob);
  file.setName(fileName);
}
```

Hope if someone can explain me the issue's source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the iterator when you deal with `folder` or `file`.

I think there is not hitting result with the `folderName`.

```js
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName); 
if (folders.hasNext()) {
  var driveFolder = folders.next();
}
```

Reference:
[FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
`var options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}
  var blobresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var blob=blobresponse.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() +".pdf" );
   var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName); 
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
  var driveFolder = folders.next();}
  var file = driveFolder.createFile(blob);
  file.setName(fileName);`


But I'm having this error now:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createFile' of undefined

Comment: There is not search result so no folder is defined.

Comment: How can I remedy to this situation ?

Comment: You defined the folder name in named range `NumAff`. How come such folder not existing? It is not even a problem of the code.

Comment: @Mous Put everything upto `file.setName` inside the `if` block `{}`

Comment: @TheMaster your suggestion solved the issue. Thank you so much !